# how to determine if my ractive computed value has changed

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

For my Layout I have a component which needs to be initialized once rendering is completed, and then again if anything in my data changes.

This would work great, but I rely on computed values for a filtered and changed output for each client and via `observe` the change event is fired to often. What I do:

```
let myRactive = new Ractive({
    el: '#clientContainer',
    template: myTemplate,
    magic: true,
    modifyArrays: true,
    data: {data}, //=> this is an awful lot of Data changing all the Time
    computed: {
        usefulData(){
           let tempdata = this.get('data');
           //=> a lot of rearranging, filtering and sorting 
           //   to adapt the data only for this specific client
           return tempdata;
        }
   onrender: function () {
        initmyLayoutComponent()
    }
    });
```

So I tried to get it this way

```
myRactive .observe( 'usefulData', function ( newValue, oldValue, keypath)
    destroymyLayoutComponent();
    initmyLayoutComponent();
});
```

But this fired a) every time *anything* in `data`changes (even when it was something completely unrelated to `usefulData`), and b) before ractive has rendered the DOM so the component gets re-initialized to early.

Is there a way to observe only the computed value, or - which would be even better - just observe specific actions in the computed value (like I want to react to added/deleted Objects, but not to changed Values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you can do, is to actually send in a clientData obj into the template instead, and then only listen to that data.

```js
let myRactive = new Ractive({
  el: '#clientContainer',
  template: '<div>{{clientData.name}}</div><input type="text" value="{{clientData.name}}" /><div>{{email}}</div><input type="text" value="{{email}}" /><div>Clientdata changed: {{cnt}}</div>',
  magic: true,
  modifyArrays: true,
  data: {
    name: 'hallo',
    email: 'a@a.com',
    cnt: 0
  }, //=> this is an awful lot of Data changing all the Time
  computed: {
    usefulData() {
      let tempdata = this.get('name');
      // Create your own data obj
      tempdata = {
        name: 'world'
      };
      // set it to the ractive context
      this.set('clientData', tempdata);
    }
  },
  oninit: function() {
    this.observe('clientData', function(newValue, oldValue, keypath) {
      let cnt = this.get('cnt')
      cnt += 1;
      this.set('cnt', cnt);
      console.log('listen only to the computed data');
    }, {init: false});
    this.get('usefulData');
  },
  onrender: function() {
    // do something
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ractive/0.9.0-build-123/ractive.min.js"></script>
<div id="clientContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will give this approach a try, and try to adjust my original script.